# Collectionview the end Draging Position dont stop on each cell

Tags: swift, collectionview

could somebody help me?
I have Collection view with insets, Scroll Direction Horizontal, Paging enables and no space between cells. And the issue is that the paging doesn't stop on each cell.

I tried all possible solution which I can find on StackOverflow and the World Wide Web but nothing works. I use Xcode 10 and Swift5 and this is for an iPhone app. I don't add my collectionviewcell code because it have only the IBoutlet for the Label.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, 
     UICollectionViewDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private let item = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday", "Sunday"]
    private let cellScaling: CGFloat = 0.33
    private var cellWidth: CGFloat = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UpdateUI()
    }

    func UpdateUI(){
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        let cellWidth = floor(screenSize.width * cellScaling)
        let insetX = (view.bounds.width - cellWidth) / 2
        let layout = collectionView!.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: collectionView.bounds.height)

        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: insetX, bottom: 0, right: insetX)

     // layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        self.cellWidth = cellWidth
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.item.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.label.text = self.item[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        return cell
    }

    private var startingScrollingOffset = CGPoint.zero

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        startingScrollingOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        let page: CGFloat
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.contentInset.left
        let proposedPage = offset / max(1, cellWidth)
        let snapPoint: CGFloat = 0.1
        let snapDelta: CGFloat = offset > startingScrollingOffset.x ? (1-snapPoint) : snapPoint

        if floor(proposedPage + snapDelta) == floor(proposedPage){
            page = floor(proposedPage)
        } else {
            page = floor(proposedPage + 1)
        }

        targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: cellWidth * page, y: targetContentOffset.pointee.y)

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRrPh.png)

And please Notice that I tried all other solution what I could find. Before you vote to delete this Question. the photo shows what it should look like on every cell.

Comment: #Rey-Bruno I change you Code a little bit!. I change "else if velocity.x == 0" to "else" because you catch all other possible results before! Thank you for your solution!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a similar collection view a few months ago,
This is the code that I use:

```
   func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let layout = theNameOfYourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout 
        let cellWidthIncludingSpacing = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing // Calculate cell size
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let index = (offset + scrollView.contentInset.left) / cellWidthIncludingSpacing // Calculate the cell need to be center

        if velocity.x > 0 { // Scroll to -->
            targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: ceil(index) * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.right, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        } else if velocity.x < 0 { // Scroll to <---
            targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: floor(index) * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        } else if velocity.x == 0 { // No dragging
            targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: round(index) * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        }
    }
```

This code calculates the size of your cell, how many cells have already been shown and once the scroll is finished, adjust it to leave the cell centered.

Make sure you have the `pagingEnabled` of your collectionView in `false` if you want to use this code.

I hope I help you!

Comment: Also, I dont need use the other scrollViewDelegate functions, only that.